# I can't access the ArangoDB web UI

Tags: arangodb, webui

I have installed ArangoDB on an AWS ubuntu EC2 instance and installed all the necessary ArangoDB packages.

However, I do not know how I can access the WebUI on port 8529, since when I enter http: // ip-instance: 8529 in the browser I receive an error.

Port 8529 is enabled in the security group of the instance. Do I have to execute any command in the terminal to be able to access the WebUI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default (after install) the ArangoDB UI is only available to the localhost (127.0.0.1).

You need to make that public. Here's how:

- Edit the `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf` file, and change the `endpoint` option to:

```
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
```

This will enable access to the UI for any outside IP address. You can also set it to be available only from a specific IP address, or under a specific DNS name (you will see examples for this in the config file itself.

- Restart the arangodb3 service: `sudo systemctl restart arangodb3`

After that you will be able to access the UI from your computer.